# Display logo in Android 5 (Lollipop) in status bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

Does anybody know if it is still possible to display a logo in the action bar on Android 5? It seems that using android:logo does not work anymore. I cannot find anything in the documentation about it.

Comment: `Toolbar.setLogo()`?

Comment: Does not seem to work on the Nexus 5, instead of a logo, the space is just empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging around, I found an answer. In order to display the logo in holo, you need to call both of the following methods:

```
actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Comment: where I need to call it onCreate of activity ?

Comment: Yes, just call it in the onCreate method.